# On an iPad 2 which is partly responsive touch, how to check if digitizer cable or rather, connector is broken?

Tags: ipad, touchscreen, digitizer

My left side (around 15% towards the edge) of iPad 2 has become unresponsive to touch, after I replaced with the wifi antenna. I checked the digitizer connector cable and it fits ok in the connector on the motherboard inside the iPad. I can pull it out and back in again, and it is the same result, so I don't know whether I should buy a new digitizer, or perhaps something in the motherboard is broken. How can I check this, anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly the best way to check would be with another whole display assembly. It sounds like it could be the actual digitizer layer (sits under the LCD display that is covered by the gorilla glass) or at least part of it that's broken. If the cable was the issue  if expect the whole display to stop responding to touch. Good thing is the part is easy to find, ifixit should be able to help with that and any tools you might need.

Comment: hey, thanks! so which part beneath the lcd should i look at? (or rather, COULD I look at)

Comment: i mean, where exactly below the LCD is it?

Comment: Sadly the display and digitizer are fused as one unit. Apple started doing this a while back. With some effort though you can separate the layers however this may come at the cost of the whole display no longer working.

Comment: No, I can see the two parts separatly, the digitizer is completely detached from the LCD - or do you mean there is a third part welded into one of these two parts?

Comment: I ordered the digitizer and will try to replace it, and see if that solves the problem. If it doesn't, I guess I'm ...... out of luck :)

Comment: I bought a new digitizer, put it in. Voila! Whole touch surface now works! :)